# Logic Apps "status": 400, "message": "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to seek your help regarding my current issue in Logic Apps, we're trying to get data from Sharepoint and will ingest data to SQL Server but we're getting this error:

""status": 400,"message": "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Can you please help us how we can fix this issue?
[image]
[image]

We're expecting to run the Logic Apps successfully.

Comment: Can you please share the screen of this action in design and not the output screenshot and what is the data you want to insert, be specific

Comment: Hi RithwikBojja, Thank you for the quick response. Sure, please see the screenshot in the new answer as I cannot add screenshot here.

Comment: Add the screenshot of the input you want to send to sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Logic Apps "status": 400, "message": "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I think, you are taking data from excel so, below would be my approach to solve it:

**`Design:`**

```
addDays('1900-01-01', 41865)
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

this is how you add days when you get the date from the excel.

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja, Thank you so much for the help. Last question, how can I correct this to the current date? Per checking the table in the database, the dates still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the help @RithwikBojja. Last question, how can I correct this to the current date? Per checking the table in the database, the dates still not showing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHtik.png)

Comment: Open a new question regarding this with complete explanation.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @RithwikBojja. I already posted a new question. Looking forward you can help me.